# Can't change image of UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

.h

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *photoImageView;
UIImage *photo;
```

.m (in viewWillAppear)

```
photoImageView.image = photo;
```

After view appeared, I can't change `photoImageView` by using:

```
photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"XXX.png"];
```

but changing the value of `photo` works.

```
photo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"XXX.png"];
```

How does it work?

Comment: Are you saying that if you change the iVar 'photo', the image in photoImageView also changes?  Based on what you've shown so far it shouldn't do that, but you might need to post more code to give us a better idea of what's going on.  Are you changing the iVar directly or using a property accessor?  If you're using a property accessor, how is it implemented?

Answer (score 5):

Try this code.

```
//YourController.h

@interface YourController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView* _photoImageView;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoImageView;

- (IBAction)changeImageAction:(id)sender;

@end

//YourController.m

@synthesize photoImageView = _photoImageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
}

- (IBAction)changeImageAction:(id)sender {

    self.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_2.png"];
}
```

**Some notes.**

First of all, you have to link your `photoImageView` IBOutlet correctly in XCode. For test purposes I created a test button (`UIButton`) that is linked to an `IBAction`. The `UIImageView` and the test button (I created both with IB) are childs of `YourController` view.

Remember to import your images into your project and to release memory in `dealloc` and in `viewDidUnload`.

```
- (dealloc)
{
   [_photoImageView release];
   _photoImageView = nil;

   [super dealloc]
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
   [super viewDidUnload];

   self.photoImageView = nil;
}
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

The code is not ARC oriented but with few modifications it is possible to run it also with ARC.

Comment: he does not want a solution of the situation. he just want to understand why it is happening..!!

Comment: @samfisher you are right! but providing the steps which in my opinion are right, it could be an help to understand what is going on. Thanks.